# How can I save the output from a subprocess to a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, subprocess, metadata, exiftool

I'm working on a script to extract exif data (Latitude, Longitude, and Altitude) from RTK drone images.  I have more or less copied the code below from a youtube video (Franchyze923)- with a few modifications. [I've been coding for a very short time].  How can I get the results of the subprocess to save to a table/dataframe (eventually I want to save the information to a .csv).

A different version of this script generated a .csv for every image - which I then imported all the csv files and pd.concat() them into one dataframe. That works but seems clunky.

```
import os
import subprocess

#Extracting exif data for images in Agisoft folder

exiftool_location = #path to exiftool.exe
images_to_extract_exif = #path to images

for path, directories, files in os.walk(images_to_extract_exif):
    for images_to_extract_exif in files:
        if images_to_extract_exif.endswith("JPG"):
            full_jpg_path = os.path.join(path, images_to_extract_exif)
            exiftool_command = [exiftool_location, "-filename", "-gpslatitude", "-gpslongitude", "-gpsaltitude", "-T", "-n", full_jpg_path]
            subprocess.run(exiftool_command)
```

The output from the code looks great - I just have no clue how to save it to a table/dataframe.

```
DJI_0001.JPG    45.2405341666667    -95.3808298055556   354.427
DJI_0002.JPG    45.2405253333333    -95.3808253055556   354.434
DJI_0003.JPG    45.2404568888889    -95.3808200277778   354.447
DJI_0004.JPG    45.2403695277778    -95.3808205555556   354.431
```

Comment: While I can't help with the question of saving the data to a table, it appears to me that this code makes [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3), which is running exiftool once for every single file.  As exiftool's startup time is its biggest performance hit, this increase processing time significantly.  A better option would be to pass the directory to exiftool and use the [`-ext` (`-extension`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#ext-EXT---ext-EXT--extension) to limit processing to jpgs.

Comment: I don't know what language your code is in but I would guess that your entire loop could be replaced with `exiftool_command = [exiftool_location, "-filename", "-gpslatitude", "-gpslongitude", "-gpsaltitude", "-T", "-n", "-ext", "jpg", images_to_extract_exif]` followed by the run command.

Comment: @StarGeek -- Thanks for the reply and for pointing me in the common mistake direction - I'm reading through that now.  What you said about performance was a separate question I was trying to figure out as well.  I'll try out the -ext option and see how that goes.

By the way - I'm writing in Python...sorry for not including that in my initial qustion.

Comment: Another option is to use a wrapper such as [PyExiftool](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/). This starts exiftool once using its [`-stay_open` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#stay_open-FLAG) and allows for file by file interaction without the startup overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to collect the ExifTool output and put in a DataFrame. Instead of using `-T` to output text I used `-j` to get json. Json can be easily read in Python so we don't have to interpret the text. By default ExifTool's json output includes a `SourceFile` tag with the file path as the value. I'll include a way to delete this tag from the output but it could be an alternative to `-filename`.

```
import json
import subprocess
import pandas as pd
# from pathlib import Path

# You can pass the dir containing all the files to ExifTool (as StarGeek suggested)
dir_path = "C:/Path/To/Dir"

# If you need to use the file paths in Python:
# fp_list = [fp for fp in Path(dir_path).iterdir()]
# cmd_list = ["exiftool", "-filename", "-gpslatitude", "-gpslongitude", "-gpsaltitude", "-j", "-n", *fp_list]

cmd_list = ["exiftool", "-filename", "-gpslatitude", "-gpslongitude", "-gpsaltitude", "-j", "-n", dir_path]
proc = subprocess.run(cmd_list, capture_output=True)
# Setting capture_output=True captures ExifTool's output in stdout and errors in stderr
exif_list = json.loads(proc.stdout)

# If you want to delete SourceFile tags:
for d in exif_list:
    del d["SourceFile"]

# exif_list = [{FileName:val, gpslatitude:val, gpslongitude:val, gpsaltitude:val}, ..., {FileName:val, gpslatitude:val, gpslongitude:val, gpsaltitude:val}]

exif_df = pd.DataFrame(exif_list)
```

`exif_df`:

|  | FileName | gpslatitude | gpslongitude | gpsaltitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | file name | val | val | val |
| 1 | file name | val | val | val |